# ¿Como rescatar multiples valores checkbox, porque solo me envía uno?

Tags: php, html

En el formulario están identificado con name=modulo[] id="modulo" y tiene su valué correspondientes a cada checkbox, la parte que me da problemas es en el que capture todo los valores seleccionados y que no mande los que no estén seleccionados. Como podría hacer eso pensé que al poner  esto me capturaría todo los checkbox, pero nada mas me captura un solo dato que podría estar mal en el php o en html en caso de que sea así. De antemano agradezco su colaboración por ayudarme en este pequeño problema

```
if(!empty($_POST['modulo'])) {
  foreach($_POST['modulo'] as $Seleccion) {

}}
```

FORMULARIO(Ojo no anexe todo el HTML del formulario por eso es que no se ven los input submit o el formulario cerrado)

```
<form action="send.php" method="POST" >
<div class="wrapper1">
    <h3>Selecciona tus ingredientes</h3>
  <div class="sub_wrapper1">
    <div class="hobby1">
      <label class="container1">
        <input type="checkbox" class="input1" name="modulo[]" id="modulo" value="JAMON">
        <span class="d_checkbox1"></span>
        <img  class="fas1" src="jamon.png"  width="30px" height="30px">
        <p>Jamon</p>
         </label>

    <div class="hobby1">
      <label class="container1">
      <input type="checkbox" class="input1" name="modulo[]" id="modulo" value="PEPPERONI">
      <span class="d_checkbox1"></span>
      <img  class="fas1" src="pepperoni.png" title="" width="30px" height="30px">
     <p>Pepperoni</p>
     </label>
```

PHP

```
<?php
    $to="alguien@gmail.com";/*Your Email*/
    $subject="Pedidos Online desde WEB";
    $date=date("l, F jS, Y");
    $time=date("h:i A");



 if(!empty($_POST['modulo'])) {
  foreach($_POST['modulo'] as $Seleccion) {

}} 

    $msg="FECHA : ".$date. ", HORA: ".$time."\n    
        Modulos :   ".$Seleccion.".";



    mail($to,$subject,$msg,"From:".$msg);
    echo "<div class='alert alert-success'>
              <a class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>×</a>
              <strong>Gracias por su mensaje!</strong>
          </div>"




?>
```

Asi me llega al correo , al yo seleccionar 3 checkbox solo me rescata uno

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No necesitas un `foreach` para esto. Basta con recuperarlo así por ejemplo: `$Seleccion=!empty($_POST['modulo']) ? implode(", ",$_POST['modulo']) : "";` Ahí, si hay datos te guardará los valores que tenga `$_POST['modulo']` separados por coma gracias a `implode`, y si no hay nada `$Seleccion` será una cadena vacía.

Answer (score 0):

No necesitas un `foreach` para esto. Basta con recuperarlo así por ejemplo:

```
$Seleccion=!empty($_POST['modulo']) ? implode(", ",$_POST['modulo']) : "Ninguno";
```

Ahí, si hay datos te guardará los valores que tenga `$_POST['modulo']` separados por coma gracias a `implode()`, y si no hay nada `$Seleccion` será una cadena igual a "Ninguno". Esta lógica puede variar en el ternario. Si no quieres mostrar nada, incorporas aquí toda la parte `"Módulos : ...."`. Así cuando no haya módulos no aparecerá nada al respecto. Eso es lo de menos, pues depende de lo que convenga mejor para tu caso.

Además, deberías someter `mail()` a prueba, no sea que haya algún fallo.

Veamos:

```
<?php
    $to="alguien@gmail.com";/*Your Email*/
    $subject="Pedidos Online desde WEB";
    $date=date("l, F jS, Y");
    $time=date("h:i A");

    $Seleccion=!empty($_POST['modulo']) ? implode(", ",$_POST['modulo']) : "Ninguno"; 

    $msg="FECHA : ".$date. ", HORA: ".$time."\n    
        Modulos :   ".$Seleccion.".";


    if ( mail($to,$subject,$msg,"From:".$msg) ) {
        echo "<div class='alert alert-success'>
              <a class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>×</a>
              <strong>Gracias por su mensaje!</strong>
          </div>";

    } else {
        echo "Error al enviar el email. Revisa tu configuración";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Me funciono Bien , Muchas gracias por el aporte

Comment: Marcalo como respuesta si te fue util